# App Engine 'Europe' pricing?

Tags: google-app-engine

Does anyone know how Google App Engine is priced when hosted in Europe?  Are there any differences to US pricing?

I ask because I'm migrating a high traffic project so we're having to try and compare as best as we can to our current Virtual Server hosted situation.

Thanks for your help,

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in pricing.

Note that you have to apply for EU site support first ([see here](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/12/app-engine-174-released.html)). As soon as you have created an app, you cannot migrate it to another site.